# capturing contents of an iframe for upload to webserver

Tags: iframe, printing, upload, screen-capture

I am trying to find a way to allow our customers to capture the contents of an iframe window and upload to our website.  Essentially, we need to be able to have them log in to one of several different websites (embedded in an iframe within our website), look up the requested document, and then capture the contents of the iframe and upload it to our webserver\SQLDB.  I have looked at using usersnap tool which sort of does the trick through email but I don't see a way to have it capture the full iframe window and autosend.  The tool needs to be hard-coded to do a full frame capture and directly upload (without the users having the ability to alter or edit the document).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Usersnap tool nearly without user interaction by hiding the button: http://usersnap.com/support/docs/javascriptext#nobutton, but however: the user has to send the screenshot by herself.

You can reach the Usersnap developers (full disclosure: including me), perhaps an easy idea can help you.